# Django Queryset based on 2-3 related tables

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have 3 related tables in the database.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Country(models.Model):
    country_code = models.CharField('Country code', unique=True, max_length=3)
    country_name = models.CharField('Country Name', max_length=25, default="")

class Customers(models.Model):
    dnr = models.CharField('Customer Nr', max_length=8, unique=True)
    dname = models.CharField('Customer Name', max_length=50, default="")
    dcountry = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BigTable(models.Model):
    deb_nr_f = models.ForeignKey(Customes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='debitor_fnr')
    sales_2016 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2016', default=0)
    sales_2017 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2017', default=0)
    sales_2018 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2018', default=0)
    sales_2019 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2019', default=0)
    sales_2020 = models.IntegerField('Abs. 2020', default=0)
```

1. How can I create a query set from two tables: Cutomers and Bigtables in this form:
   Customer Nr 1 /// Sales_2016 /// Sales_2017 /// ...
   Customer Nr 2 /// Sales_2016 /// Sales_2017 /// ...
   Customer Nr ...
2. How can I create a query set from three tables: Countries, Cutomers and BigTable in this form:
   Country Nr 1 /// Sales_2016 /// Sales_2017 /// ... 
   Country Nr 2 /// Sales_2016 /// Sales_2017 /// ... 
   Country Nr ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Watch [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships
>   in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind
>   the scenes. To span a relationship, use the field name of related
>   fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get
>   to the field you want.

1. `BigTable.objects.values('deb_nr_f__dname', 'sales_2016', 'sales_2017', ...)`
2. `BigTable.objects.values('deb_nr_f__dcountry__country_name', 'sales_2016', 'sales_2017', ...)`

if you need [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#aggregate-expressions) sum for every Customer you can do it like this

```
from django.db.models import Sum

BigTable.objects.values('deb_nr_f').order_by('deb_nr_f').annotate(2016_sum=Sum('sales_2016')).annotate(2017_sum=Sum('sales_2017'))...
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works but for a single record in Big Table only. Sorry. Forgot to mention, The Big table contains multiple records for every customer / debitor (because the turnover is structured according to the products, which is hier not relevant). How can I get in the Queryset the aggregated sales for every customer for mentioned periods of time? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying it using Customer model

**create a query set from two tables: Cutomers and Bigtables.**
Query

```
Customers.objects.values('dnr','dname','debitor_fnr__sales_2016','debitor_fnr__sales_2017'....)
```

Explanation: Here I am using lookups to access foreign key values. In BigTable model you have saved deb_nr_f as a foreign key field with related_name='debitor_fnr' for Customer model.So the record can be accessed using the related field as childmodelrelatedname__childfieldname.

**create a query set from three tables: Countries, Cutomers and BigTable**
Query

```
Customers.objects.values('dcountry__country_name','dnr','dname','debitor_fnr__sales_2016','debitor_fnr__sales_2017'....)
```

Explanation Almost similar as above, I am accesing country table with foreign key field in Customers model on 'dcountry' field. So it is like parentmodelforeignkeyfield__parentfieldname

For more info you can refer this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Comment: Thanks for the input. It works but for a single record in Big Table only. Sorry. Forgot to mention, The Big table contains multiple records for every customer / debitor (because the turnover is structured according to the products, which is hier not relevant). How can I get in the Queryset the aggregated sales for every customer for mentioned periods of time. Thank you

Comment: It can be done using annotate you can refer this documentation [link1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) . Ex for first query: `Customers.objects.values('dnr','dname').annotate(Avg('debitor_fnr__sales_2016'))`. I hope this will help you. Also for aggregation functions follow this [link2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation)